# Getting Rails working with a JS runtime environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, execjs

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and the terminal to install and run Rails.  Here
is the process I've taken so far to setup Rails:

- download and install Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.0

  -- I did this using `sudo apt-get ruby1.9.1` and `sudo gem install
  rails`
- I made a new rails app using `rails new path/to/app`
- I went to the new app directory and tried running `rails server` and got an
  error about not having a JS ruby environment
- I had to get a JS runtime environment for execjs so I downloaded 'therubyracer'
  as well as 'therubyrhino' and added them to my gem file, one at a time like this:
  `gem
  'therubyracer'` then ran `bundle install`
- After everything was successful with the install, I ran `rails server` again

  -- with both runtime environments I have had similar errors:

```
Could not find libv8-3.3.10.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Could not find therubyrhino-1.73.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Bundle knows where these programs live, giving correct pathnames when I
enter `bundle show libv8` or `bundle show therubyrhino`.  They are both
in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/*_*  where all the other gems are
located for the bundle install.

Does anyone know where this exception is coming up in the Rails source
code?  Does anyone know how Rails is gathering the gems?  Better yet,
anyone had this problem and know how to fix it?

Thanks so much,
Feav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in a newer version of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting the server using `bundle exec rails server`?